# How to get number of requests waitinng to be processed when deployed a vertx httpserver as worker verticle?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

Is there any other way to get a number of requests waiting to be processed by worker threads when deploying an HTTP server as worker verticle? I need an alternative for https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/java/#_pool_metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to utilize [Asynchronous Counters](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_counters) which you can increment whenever you send an event to specific address on event bus and then decrement when verticle is done processing (or have just picked up an event). If you have lot of verticles and don't want to modify each of them, you can set [outbound interceptor](https://vertx.io/preview/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.rxjava.core.eventbus/-event-bus/add-interceptor.html):

```
vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(deliveryContext -> {
                //you can validate if the address is what you are looking for
                if (deliveryContext.message().address().equalsIgnoreCase("http event")) {
                    //increment counter
                }
                deliveryContext.next();
            });
```

if you have a lot of addresses to cover you can always add some specific header to the message and then look for it in the interceptor but that would mean you have to modify each .send() call in worst case scenario:

```
vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(deliveryContext -> {
    //looking for specific header
    if (deliveryContext.message().headers().contains("incrementCounterHeader")) {
        //increment counter
    }
    deliveryContext.next();
});

//later in code
vertx.eventBus().send("http event", message,
        new DeliveryOptions().addHeader("incrementCounterHeader", "somevalue"));
```

last but not least if you decide to use async counter you might want to propagate message only .onComplete() or .onSuccess(), depends on your business logic.

Hope this will help!

Comment: how does this work when I deploy vertex as worker vertices. I am not specifically writing anything to event bus.

Comment: If you just have http verticle which handles requests, then what exactly do you mean by requests "waiting to be processed" by worker threads? Do you mean, frozen http request which is not handled at all cause there are no threads available at the moment? Or maybe request that have already reached requested endpoint but the processing of it is still in progress?